# How to set root construct for SnakeYaml?

Tags: snakeyaml

I'd like to a construct which is going to kick in by default and therefore I'll be able to extract some metadata and remove it from the parsed YAML.

For instance I could have a construct to do that but in SnakeYAML to register a construct one has to specify a String for it meaning that it has to have a name. However, I don't want that but instead I want my tag to be a root one, a default one which always will kick in so to say.

Is there a possibility to do something like that?

Cheers,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually found the answer myself, there is a property 
 at `org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.BaseConstructor#rootTag` which one can set a tag like:

```
super.rootTag = new Tag("!root");
```

The rest is simple because one has to only register that construct to `org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.BaseConstructor#yamlConstructors` and you are done. Your construct will be triggered in all read attempts.

Hope that helps to someone,

Cheers,